# How to implement a mouseListener

Tags: java, eclipse, actionlistener, mouselistener

I know that at the beginning of a class you can write `implements ActionListener` and then you must create `public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)` for it to be workable. Is it possible to do the same thing with the mouseListener? if so, what method do you have to create in place of `actionPerformed`?

Edit: this is my class declaration:

```
public class Basic_Book extends JFrame implements ActionListener implements MouseListener
```

And this is my error message that shows up next to it:

- The serializable class Basic_Book does not declare a static final serialVersionUID field of type 
   long
- Syntax error on token "implements", . expected

Comment: You implement mouselistener. Your IDE will tell you what methods need to be implemented. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/event/MouseListener.html

Comment: @JeroenVannevel I assume you mean `MouseListener`, right?

Comment: It is only giving errors, but does not say what needs to be implemented.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you look at the [javadocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/awt/event/MouseListener.html).. there are a bunch of methods that come with `MouseListener`. 
In other not to implement everything, you can use a `MouseAdapter` which implements `MouseListener` and other interfaces, but already providing stub methods.

`mouseClicked`, `mouseEntered` etc..
Following your edit:

```
class Basic_Book extends JFrame implements ActionListener,MouseListener
```

Use a comma to separate the interfaces. 
`ActionListener` only has `actionPerformed` so you have to implement only that for ActionListener,
`MouseListener` has 4 or more, you need to implement ALL. Or use `MouseAdapter` and override the necessary methods.

For the `serialVersionUID`, let Eclipse do that for you. Try ctrl+space on the error to invoke Eclipse's intellisense, it will give you some options. Choose the one that says generate `serialVersionUID`,

I can't remember how it is actually done (but it should work! Fingers crossed).

Comment: Is there anything like a `BasicMouseListener` so that you can @Override only the actions you care about?  It's really simple to make one yourself, but I get the feeling there could be a default one somewhere.

Comment: Perfect, much simpler than extending MouseListener, though newbies might be better off with `extends MouseListener` just for the sake of knowing what methods there are to implement.

Answer (score 2):

The [Official Java API Documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/) is an essential tool for any Java programmer. In particular, check out [the docs for MouseListener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/MouseListener.html) to see what methods you need to implement.

You can also simply add `implements MouseListener` and try to compile your class. The compiler will quickly tell you what methods you need to implement. If you are using an IDE such as Eclipse, NetBeans, or IntelliJ, you don't even need to compile your code. Each IDE has its own way of telling you what methods you need and even generate bodies of the methods for you. I strongly suggest that you familiarize yourself with a good IDE. It will save you a lot of time writing code.

Answer (score 2):

Like `ActionListener` and `MouseListener` is an interface, which means, yes, you can implement in the same way.

[`MouseListener`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/MouseListener.html) defines five methods which you must implement.

- `mouseClicked(MouseEvent e)`
- `mouseEntered(MouseEvent e)`
- `mouseExited(MouseEvent e)`
- `mousePressed(MouseEvent e)`
- `mouseReleased(MouseEvent e)`

You really should check with the [Java Docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/MouseListener.html) and [tutorials](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/mouselistener.html) first

Comment: I created those, but the errors in my edit above are still there, any suggestions?

Comment: add @Override above the five methods

Comment: @Harper Did you implement the MouseListener interface as described in the linked tutorials?

Answer (score 0):

Actually the compiler should tell you the answer but should be something like mouseLeave, mouseEnter, mouseHover, mousePressed

Comment: Actually, other then `mousePressed` none of the other methods are in any interface that I'm aware of...just saying ;)